# Taking values from one file and after some calculation and a bit changes need to print into another file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file, if-statement

below is c.txt

```
CO11 CSE C1 8
CO12 ETC C1 8
CO13 Electrical C2 12
CO14 Mech E 5
```

my program needs to print a course summary on screen and save that summary into a file
named cr.txt. Given the above c.txt, your program output should look like
below. The content of course_report.txt should also be the same, except the last line. Course
names in the second column use * to indicate a compulsory course and – to indicate an elective
course. The fourth column is the number of students enrolled in that course. The fifth column is the average score of the course.

```
CID Name Points. Enrollment. Average.
----------------------------------
CO11 * CSE 8 2 81
CO12 * ETC 8 10 71
CO13 * Electrical 12 8 61
CO14 - Mech 5 4 51
----------------------------------
poor-performing subject is CO14 with an average 51.
cr.txt generated!
```

below is what I've tried:

```
    def read(self):
        ctype = []
        fi = open("c.txt", "r")
        l = fi.readline()
        while l != "":
            fields = l.strip().split(" ")
            self.c.append(fields)
            l = fi.readline().strip()
        f.close()
        # print(f"{'CID'}{'Name':>20}{'Points.':>16}{'Enrollment.':>18}{'Average.':>10}")
        # print("-" * 67, end="")
    print()
        for i in range(0, len(self.c)):
            for j in range(len(self.c[i])):
                obj = self.c[i][j]
                print(obj.ljust(18), end="")
        print()

    print("-" * 67, end="")
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try use 'file.read' or 'file.readlines' after use 'open' function, if you choose 'file.readlines' you'll have to use 'for row in file.readlines()' look my example with 'file.read':

```
headers = ['CID', 'Name', 'Points.', 'Enrollment.', 'Average.']
compulsory_course = ['CO11', 'CO12', 'CO13']
elective_course = ['CO14']
count = 0
with open('c.txt', 'r') as file_c:
    file_c.seek(0, 0)
    file_string = file_c.read().replace('\n', ' ')
    fields = file_string.split(' ')

with open('cr.txt', 'w') as file_cr:
    for field in headers:
        file_cr.write(f'{field}    ')
    file_cr.write('\n')
    for v in fields:
        if count == 4:
            file_cr.write('\n')
            count = 0
        count += 1
        if v in compulsory_course:
            file_cr.write(f'{v} *    ')
            continue
        elif v in elective_course:
            file_cr.write(f'{v} -    ')
            continue
        elif count == 3:
            file_cr.write(f' ')
            continue
        file_cr.write(f'{v}    ')
```